# Songs package: Vertical spacing between songs

Tags: songs

I am wondering whether it is possible to remove any extra vertical spacing between songs such that all songs have the same distance between each other. In the attached example it can be seen how song no. 10 and 11 (and 5 and 6) are separated. I would like them to be close to each other with a fixed distance.

The problem only appears for \songpos{0}.

[image]
Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}

\songpos{0}
\renewcommand{\colbotglue}{0pt plus .5\textheight minus 0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{}

\beginsong{Gud er din hvile}[]
\beginchorus
Gud er din hvile, 
Kristus din styrke, 
anden er nar som en trofast ven. 
Herren har hort dig, 
nadig berort dig, 
Herren vil rejse dig op igen
\endchorus
\endsong
\beginsong{I min Gud har jeg fundet styrke}[]
\beginchorus
I min Gud har jeg fundet styrke
I min Herre bor min sang.
For han skanker frelse og fred.
Pa ham jeg stoler, min frygt forgar,
Pa ham jeg stoler, min frygt forgar.
\endchorus
\endsong
\beginsong{Jesus, Guds son}[]
\beginchorus
Jesus, Guds son, du lys i mit indre
lad ikke morket fa magten i mit sind
Jesus, Guds, son, du lys i mit indre
luk mig op for din karligheds and
\endchorus
\endsong
\beginsong{Jesus remember me}[]
\beginchorus
Jesus remember me
when you come into your kingdom. 
Jesus, remember me
when you come into your kingdom
\endchorus
\endsong
\beginsong{Jordens morke er ikke morke}[]
\beginchorus
Jordens morke er ikke morke, Gud, for dig:
som dagens klare lys bliver natten.
\endchorus
\endsong
\beginsong{Gud er din hvile}[]
\beginchorus
Gud er din hvile, 
Kristus din styrke, 
anden er nar som en trofast ven. 
Herren har hort dig, 
nadig berort dig, 
Herren vil rejse dig op igen
\endchorus
\endsong
\beginsong{I min Gud har jeg fundet styrke}[]
\beginchorus
I min Gud har jeg fundet styrke
I min Herre bor min sang.0For han skanker frelse og fred.
Pa ham jeg stoler, min frygt forgar,
Pa ham jeg stoler, min frygt forgar.
\endchorus
\endsong
\beginsong{Jesus, Guds son}[]
\beginchorus
Jesus, Guds son, du lys i mit indre
lad ikke morket fa magten i mit sind
Jesus, Guds, son, du lys i mit indre
luk mig op for din karligheds and
\endchorus
\endsong
\beginsong{Jesus remember me}[]
\beginchorus
Jesus remember me
when you come into your kingdom. 
Jesus, remember me
when you come into your kingdom
\endchorus
\endsong
\beginsong{Jordens morke er ikke morke}[]
\beginchorus
Jordens morke er ikke morke, Gud, for dig:
som dagens klare lys bliver natten.
\endchorus
\endsong

\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please add a minimal (working) example to your post? It would help solvers a lot to get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Set `\songpos{0}`?

Comment: \songpos{0} is already set.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Please try to make your document example more minimal.  A minimal document should include nothing that is unnecessary for exhibiting the problem.  For example, avoid loading any other packages, avoid customizing any settings, and avoid redefining any macros.  This will make diagnosing your problem much easier.

Comment: Using the style found at https://github.com/Carreau/songbook/blob/master/songs.sty, I am not able to recreate the OP's problem of excessive gap.

Comment: @KevinHamlen: I have minimized the example now.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I'm using the 2013 version. Do you think that makes a difference?

Comment: I don't know, but I would say that your MWE has 10 songs in it, while your picture shows songs through #13.  So, obviously, your picture did not come from the MWE you posted.

Comment: Actually it worked to downgrade to 2.15 (2010) version. Thanks for the help.

Comment: However, it is not really a good solution since other features doesn't work in 2.15.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for minimizing your working example.  After much digging, your minimized example enabled me to track down a longstanding, elusive bug in the songs package programming that is causing this problem.  The bug will be fixed in the next release of the software (should be 2.19).  Here is a workaround and manual fix you can use in the meantime:

1. Most users who have unwanted whitespace between songs are not witnessing a bug; they unintentionally have `\colbotglue` set to 0pt, forcing the songs package to end each column flush with the bottom of the page.  When there isn't enough material to fill the column, gaps can appear between the songs.  Thus, the usual solution is to adjust the `\colbotglue` macro as described in the following answer to a similar question:

   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108259/28900
2. If you continue to see space between songs even after the above correction, it may be the result of the aforementioned bug (appearing in songs versions up to and including 2.18).  You can often work around the bug by redefining `\colbotglue` to be something strong enough to offset the unwanted `\vfil` that is creating the extra space.  For example:

   ```
   \renewcommand\colbotglue{0pt plus 1fill minus 0pt}
   ```

   This solves the problem in your minimal working example.
3. To correct the bug at the heart of the problem, you can manually edit your `songs.sty` file in the following way:  In version 2.18 of the package, find the definition of the `\SB@mkpage` macro.  Within its definition, replace the line that says,

   ```
   \global\setbox#2\vbox{\unvbox\SB@tempii\unskip}%
   ```

   with the following:

   ```
   \global\setbox#2\box\SB@tempii
   ```

   Then, immediately after the line that says `\repeat`, add the following line of code:

   ```
   \ifnum#1=\z@\global\setbox#2\vbox{\unvbox#2\unskip}\fi
   ```

   This correction is expected to be included in version 2.19.

(For the curious: The problem is that the page-maker temporarily appends `\vfil` to suppress underfull box warnings while trying out candidate column breaks.  The extra `\vfil` is supposed to be removed once a final column breakpoint is selected, but if the algorithm "gets lucky" and finds a perfect column breakpoint on its first try without any backtracking, it forgets to remove the `\vfil`.)

Comment: The colbotglue doesn't work as you can see in the updated minimal working example. Any ideas?

Comment: Answer updated to identify and correct a bug in the package code.  I apologize that it has taken so long to finally get an answer.  This particular bug was quite tricky to identify, partly because others who observed it were not able to reliably reproduce it with a minimal example.  I appreciate the questioner's effort in minimizing his/her example, so that I could finally track it down.